# JPQL query statement for one sided many-to-many relation in spring with hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpql

I have two entities **actor** and **community** with many-to-many relationsip as below:

```
**Actor.java**

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "membership",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "member_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "community_id") }
    )
    private Set<Community> communities;
```

I just need the JPQL for getting communities that are related as from the membership table for a specific actor. I know I can find the communities by just accessing the set defined here and hibernate will generate the queries all by itself. But I need the jpql because I will be using it as a subquery for a larger query.

```
**1**
SELECT community FROM Community community JOIN Actor actor ON actor.communities WHERE actor = :member
```

```
**2**
SELECT community FROM Community community JOIN Actor actor ON actor.communities WHERE actor = :member
```

and many more that I haven't kept track of.